# Should the <i>-tag contain a language attribute if used to mark up foreign language words?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, epub, lang

Typographically, italic type is used, among other uses, to mark up foreign language text:

> The Roman soldier pointed his *pilum* at me.

In the HTML/XHTML/XML code of an EPUB, should the <i>-Tag contain a language attribute? Here is a simplified example:

```
<html xml:lang="en">
...
    <p>The Roman soldier pointed
    his <i xml:lang="la">pilum</i>
    at me.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a link in the Sigil forums I actually found an explicit [recommendation by the IDPF](https://idpf.github.io/a11y-guidelines/content/xhtml/lang.html) to mark up foreign passages in that way. The example they give contains the following code, where a French passage is marked up in containing English text:

```
<i xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">C'est vendredi saint!</i>
```

Comment: The [HTML5 spec for the `<i>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) agrees. It says "Terms in languages different from the main text should be annotated with lang attributes (or, in XML, lang attributes in the XML namespace)." and gives an example '<p>There is a certain <i lang="fr">je ne sais quoi</i> in the air.</p>'